# Hide non primary/foreign key columns in EA data model

Tags: data-modeling, enterprise-architect

Hei,
I want to display in EA a data model for an existing database containing about 150 tables, the primary objective being to show the relations between the tables and the logic of the database.
I imported first the tables definition using the EA ODBC import function, so far so good. But now, to display a simpler diagram, I would like to hide all non primary/foreign key columns. How can I do that?
Tried the following:

- Right click in the diagram and go to "Properties/Elements/Show Compartments" I can deselect "Attributes" - but ALL columns will be hidden
- Same as above and select "Operations", this display the operation associated with the primary/foreign, NOT the columns themselves

I dont want to manually remove the columns because first it is a lot of work and 2nd I still want to be able to access the columns properties when selecting a table. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide key information from table in ERD in Sparx EA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341146/how-to-hide-key-information-from-table-in-erd-in-sparx-ea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually hide the attributes (columns) on a diagram.

Right click on an element and select **Features & Properties|Feature and Compartment visibility**

Then click on the custom button in the Attributes section and select only those that you want to show/hide

Comment: Ok, this is a good start: it does what I want BUT is manual. In this data model there are 150 tables, maybe 2000 columns in total... So is this something that can be automated? Via EA Scripting maybe?

Comment: Yes it can, but you'll need a strong stomach. It involves editing the styleEx type fields which contain a series of key-value pairs to indicate which attributes to show an which to hide.