# How to hide key information from table in ERD in Sparx EA?

Tags: enterprise-architect, erd

How to hide key information from table depiction in ERD in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open the context menu of the element
- Features.../...Visibility
- in the Hide Stereotypes box enter `PK,FK`

That should hide them.